# How to delete DBXsvc.exe service after uninstalling Dropbox

Tags: windows, windows-8, dropbox

After uninstalling Dropbox and rebooting my PC multiple times, I still see the service `DBXsvc.exe` running in Task Manager.

Why is this process still on my computer after uninstalling Dropbox, and how can I remove it?

Comment: One option to delete the service would be:
1. Run Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), look at the properties to see it's startup location I assume it's a service key.  Maybe also get the service name from the services tab to double check.

2. Run in an admin command prompt: `sc delete servicename` where you can replace the servicename with that as discovered in step 1.  

If you know the name of the service, i.e. you can find it in services.msc just go straight to step 2 to delete.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EMK, I found similar solution [Why is DBXsvc still running after uninstall of the program](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Why-is-DBXsvc-still-running-after-uninstall-of-the-program/td-p/199657) that works for me. open a cmd prompt (Run as admin) - type net stop dbxsvc, then type sc delete dbxsvc. if you can post an answer then i can accept it.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator - added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove a service registration from the service control manager database using the command line tool sc.exe.

In this case DBXsvc.exe is a Windows service called "dbxsvc".  To delete this service, in an administrative command prompt perform the following:

First, check if it is running:

```
sc query dbxsvc
```

If so, I would suggest stopping it before deleting it:

```
sc stop dbxsvc
```

You can then delete it:

```
sc delete dbxsvc
```

Clearly the uninstaller should remove services it installed but this approach can be used to clean up where needed.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that yes, [DbxSvc.exe is installed alongside Dropbox](http://www.file.net/process/dbxsvc.exe.html), meaning it should theoretically be safe to remove after uninstalling Dropbox.